# How to do something when user touches canvas? Assistance to check bounds

Tags: java, android, bitmap, touch, android-canvas

Hi I drew a bitmap on the canvas and I wanted to do something when the user touches it.

```
Bitmap backbutton = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.backbutton);
    Paint paint = new Paint();

canvas.drawBitmap(backbutton, canvasWidth - 100, 0, paint);
```

I have tried the following to solve the problem but it isnt working. How do I check for inbounds properly?

```
public void onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if(backbutton.contains((int) (event.getX()), (int)(event.getY()), (int)(event.getX()+100),(int) (event.getY()+30))) {
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "this works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

But I seem to be doing something wrong with the `contains()`. Can someone help me out here please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the rect of the bitmap on the canvas. then in the `onTouchEvent`, check the touched x, y is contained in the rect before.

Added Example:

```
public class MyView extends View {
Rect bitmapRect;
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Rect source = new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    bitmapRect = new Rect(0,0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, source, bitmapRect, new Paint());

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y =   (int)event.getY();
    if(null != bitmapRect && bitmapRect.contains(x,y)){
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "this works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);    //To change body of overridden methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}
```

}

Comment: @User1204501 see my added example.

Comment: works like a charm! Has a question though. How can I display the button on the top right hand corner of the canvas?

Comment: ` int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
            Rect source = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            Rect bitmapRect = new Rect(canvasWidth - bitmap.getWidth(), 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, source, bitmapRect, new Paint());`

Comment: it displays a weird shape =( I will award you the correct answer so you get the points but if you figure it out then can you let me know please?

Comment: have you changed the bitmap resource?

Comment: Yes, but only a slightly. I just changed the dimensions 100x40 now

Comment: the cause is the `bitmapRect` because I want it to appear on the top right corner but what it does is takes over the top of the screen except the corner